# Tricky(?) Singularity classification question

Tags: complex-analysis

Find and classify isolated singularities of:

$$\frac{1}{\sin z-\sin2z}$$

So I have found the singularities to be:
$z=k\pi,(6k \pm1)\pi/3$

Now i could factor these out of $f(z)=\sin z-\sin 2z$ to give:

$(z-k\pi)(z-(6k \pm1)\pi/3)g(z)$ and the use the theorem that if:

$f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$ and has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$.

However am I correct in thinking that I do not know the order (multiplicity) of say $(z-k \pi)$?

What is the best approach to this question?

Answer (score 0):

At any point where $f(z)$ has a zero and $f'(z)$ is not zero, $1/f(z)$ has a simple pole.  ("Simple" = multiplicity $1$.)

$$
\sin z - \sin(2z) = \sin z - 2\sin z\cos z = (\sin z)(1-2\cos z)
$$
Both of these two factors have nonzero derivatives where they are zero, so you have a simple pole at each zero of $\sin z$ and at each zero of $1-2\cos z$.

I think it may be easy to show there's an essential singularity at $\infty$.